# fstab folder bind on partition mounted with defaults parameter

Tags: permissions, fstab

I want bind some folders in my Home directory with some folders in a NTFS partition. Will mounting the NTFS partition with only the `defaults` parameter affect my read/write access?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but `defaults` for NTFS means full permissions for users.

Comment: @htorque, that's exactly what I wanted to know - answered myself from Googling a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mounting a partition with `defaults` parameter will give all users read/write access. As quoted from [Swerdna's openSUSE mounting tutorial](http://opensuse.swerdna.org/susentfs.html#permanent):

> To mount your NTFS partition
>   permanently, add your version of the
>   following line into the file system
>   table, `fstab`. [and leave the last line
>   in the file as a blank line.]
>   Recommended option for world-writeable
>   mount:
>
> ```
> /dev/sdb1    /path_to/mount_point    ntfs-3g    defaults    0 0
> ```
>
> When you reboot, the partion will
>   mount into the folder
>   /path_to/mount_point with permissions
>   drwxrwxrwx, i.e with read/write access
>   for everybody, in the style of
>   Microsoft's insecure filesystems.

Comment: Note that only root will be allowed to mount this drive with option `defaults`. If non-root users need to be able to mount use option `users` (example given in my answer).

Comment: @Takkat, won't using `defaults` mount the partition on boot? So users won't be able to unmount (since it was done by root) and subsequently won't need the ability to remount.

Comment: If it was an external drive it could get unplugged (by accident) and couldn't be remounted without reboot or root-access. Not much of a problem but worth noting.

Answer (score 5):

Default mount options are:

```
rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,async
```

This means that by using `defaults` in fstab the drive will be:

- `rw`: read-write
- `suid`: set-user-identifier  or set-group-identifier bits take effect
- `dev`: interpret character or block special devices
- `exec`: permit execution of binaries
- `auto`: auto-mount or allow `mount -a`
- `nouser`: only root is allowed to mount
- `async`: I/O to the filesystem should be  done  asynchronously

These options can be adapted to personal needs. All possible options are listed in the [mount manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/mount.8.html).

For mounting an NTFS filesystem you may want to add the options: `uid=0,gid=46,umask=007,nls=utf8`.

This would be an example `fstab` entry for NTFS-filesystem using LABEL rather than UUID where all users are allowed to mount:

```
LABEL="NTFS_Disk"   /media/windows   ntfs  umask=007,gid=46,uid=0,nls=utf8,noauto,users   0       0
```

Comment: It does say `rw`, but to who? To root? To user? That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: @Oxwivi: All users are able to read and write with option `rw`.

Comment: I chose my own answer since you did not include what I wanted to know in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The word "bind" appears in the title, but appears not to be addressed on this page. I fell upon a configuration which seems to work (add to `/etc/fstab`):

```
# <file system>           <mount point>             <type>     <options>                                <dump>  <pass>
UUID=3030BD846F74E514     /media/iam/ntfspartition  ntfs-3g    uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=022,fmask=133    0       0
/media/iam/ntfspartition  /e                        ntfs-3g    bind                                     0       0
```

To find `UUID`, compare

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

For `uid`, use `echo $UID`.

I'm very new to minding my permissions, users, groups, mounting and binding, and other factors, so if anyone has comments, please advise.

Comment: Immediately ran into problems with permission, so I changed `022` and `133` to `077` and `177`.