# Make ubuntu not mount my Win-7 disk as random hash

Tags: mount

Right now, I use my windows 7 HDD as data-disk for Ubuntu, where I store my music and documents.

The problem is that the hard drive is mounted with a random hash or something every time I boot, so the path is never the same(Example: `/media/petterroea/A26677AA66777E3B`). How can I make it mount to a permanent path?

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't be like that. Always that I mount my NTFS partitions it shows the same UIID.

Answer (score 4):

First open a terminal and type "mount" you should see something like this:

```
/dev/sda2 on /media/jeffery/76C8AE3CC8ADFB0F type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Keep track of the /dev/sdX# value.

Next, edit fstab via:

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

At the end, add a line like this, changing to match the line above:

```
/dev/sda2  /media/windows-data ntfs rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096
```

After saving the change, you can reboot or do:

```
sudo umount /media/Petterroea/A26677AA66777E3B
sudo mount -a
mount
```

You should now see a line via mount that says:

```
/dev/sda2 on /media/windows-data type fuseblk ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the mount options using the "Disk" utility. Open the Dash, type Disk, then enter. You will presented with a screen like this:

[image: enter code here]

Select your partition of your HDD, then select the small cogs icon. You will have a screen like this:

[image]

Just turn off the Automatic Mount Options, and select the "Mount Point" where you like the drive mounted, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a partition has no label it will be mounted using its UUID. To give it more sensible names we may add a label to a partition:

- [How to rename partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions)

We can then also mount this drive from the [fstab by label](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49371/fstab-folder-bind-on-partition-mounted-with-defaults-parameter) rather than by UUID in case we want to auto-mount it on boot.