# How to edit label of USB drive?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

How to edit label of USB drive easily without formatting it? I tried right clicking the device and go to the properties but cannot find anything to edit.

Comment: You did not specify if this USB drive is Linux only (ie. ext formatted).

Comment: Specify the file system.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/a/53469/3940 and http://askubuntu.com/a/49296/3940

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### From Terminal

You have to use the mlabel command.

- First type the mount command to find out the device location of you pen drive. Find the line which goes like “/dev/sdc1 on /media/disk …”.
- This means the device sdc1 which is my pen drive is mounted on /media/disk.
- Next unmount the device.

  sudo umount /media/disk
- Next use this command.

  `sudo mlabel -i /dev/sdc1 ::<new_label>`

#### If you get a message like:

Total number of sectors (7831520) not a multiple of sectors per track (63)!
    You can easily ignore the check by running this command:

`echo mtools_skip_check=1 >> ~/.mtoolsrc`

Try again and it should work.

- The name of the USB should have changed. Unplug and Plug the pen drive back in and it will be mounted with the new label name.

#### The GUI way

- For this you need the Gparted software. Install it if you don’t have it already.
- Open the software as a super user, and select the pen drive from GParted>Devices>
- Unmount the device if it hasn’t been, by right clicking on it.
- After unmounting, right click on it and select “Label” and change it to whatever you want it to be. And then Apply it, by clicking the Edit>Apply All Operations.
- Your pendrives label should be changed now.

### [Original Source](http://techbu.com/2009/06/28/renaming-usb-drive-labels-in-linux)

Comment: I am using sudo mlabel -i /dev/sde1 ::<Namshum> but getting the error bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: The GUI way works out as per the steps you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you are using the command line technique, you may need to enclose the mount point in quotes to unmount it, viz:

sudo umount "/media/STORE N GO"

Comment: In my case, I had to add MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 to the /etc/mtools.conf to get it working (~/.mtoolsrc din't exist). Good answer anyway. It works fine.

Comment: ~/.mtoolsrc doesn't work here since it goes to the users home directory. you have to edit /root/.mtoolsrc (or the config)

Comment: If you use GParted you still need `mtools` package.

Comment: @karthick87 Can't I give image in the label using mlabel? see https://lifehacker.com/188852/assign-a-custom-icon-to-your-flash-drive

Answer (score 19):

You got several options (some require installation). Out of these `e2label` should be the easiest.

> Gparted

Gparted can do this. Rightclick the device and choose label. Needs installation of gparted though.

---

There are several command line methods:

> `tune2fs`  - Adjust  tunable  filesystem  parameters  on  ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems

Example: `sudo tune2fs -L {label} {devicename}`

---

> `e2label`  - Change the label on an ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem

Example: `sudo e2label {device} {label}`

---

There is also the Windows method:

> `mlabel`  - make an MSDOS volume label

Add a line in the `/etc/mtools.conf` file like this `drive {letter}: file="{device}"`. Example: drive p: file="/dev/sdb1". Note that the drive letter can be replaced by any letter that is not present in the mtools.conf file.

Example to set the label: `sudo mlabel {letter}:{label}`

Comment: What does it mean when the "Label" right-menu option is disabled in `gparted`?

Answer (score 11):

As well as the other answers, the more ubiquitous tool `dosfslabel` is well suited to this task;

```
dosfslabel /dev/sdd1 "My Label"
```

where `/dev/sdd1` is the partition you wish to label.

Answer (score 5):

I did a little research and I found this official tutorial from **Ubuntu Documentation** which will teach you **step by step** how to rename drives with different file systems (**FAT16, FAT32, NTFS, ext2, ext3, ext4, JFS, ReiserFS (v3) and XFS**).

The title is "RenameUSBDrive", but it is not only for USB drives, it covers a lot of file systems supported by Ubuntu.

**Here is the link**: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive

Answer (score 0):

Gparted and Mlabel did not work on Ubuntu 18.04 renaming a FAT USB drive. However, you can use **`fatlabel`** instead :

```
sudo fatlabel /dev/sdd1 NEWNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Another GUI way if you're using Gnome.

1. run `gnome-disks` or search for "Disks" in the app search
2. Choose the device
3. choose the partition, click the gear icon

   [image]
4. Modify the Display Name field

   [image]