# Drive Name in Windows

Tags: windows, drive

I have windows 8.1 and Ubuntu installed.  If I change the Ubuntu partition name in Windows, will that cause me problems in Ubuntu (or Windows)?

I'll add that Windows 8.1 was installed on the machine and I first partitioned the drive in Windows before installing Ubuntu.   Now, I want to change the drive name in Windows.

I cannot imagine this is a problem, but I'd rather ask than find out how limited my imagination is the hard way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the label should not cause problems between Windows and Ubuntu. In both cases, references to the disk are to the device in Linux (like /dev/sdX) or to the letter in Windows (like D:/). The label is really just for the user's benefit.

You may feel more comfortable editing the label from Ubuntu instead:

[How to rename partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions)