# How to change the name of the mountpoint of a Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on VMware workstation 12 (my host OS is Win10). When I installed Ubuntu I made the Hard Disk of 20 GB but later I expanded it to 50 GB.
So, that expanded 30 GB now appear as a new partition.
My problem is when I mount it, it is mounted at [image]

> /media/username/0d780fd1-5c53-4ad4-b7ea-bdae88aad04a

with a random number sequence. so whenever I needed to go that partition in terminal I have to copy-paste that long sequence and it is really painful to do that every time.

**Is there any way to turn this long number sequence into a text**? (I mean something like a label, say "newpart", so I can use cd /media/username/newpart to move into it).

Comment: Have you tried mounting the partition in question via /etc/fstab? Have you seen https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Answer (score 1):

We can assign a [label](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions) to any partition which will then be mounted to `/media/username/<label`.

In case we need permanent access to the drive we may want to consider mounting them to a defined mountpoint (i.e. a directory we need to create first). The partition will be automatically mounted when defined by an entry to `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=<uuid>    <mountpoint>    ext4    defaults   0  2
```

By this we may create symbolic links in our HOME to directories on that extra partition, or we may [move our entire HOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive/50539?s=10%7C0.0000#50539) to there.

Consider to make a snapshot before experimenting with partitions and mount points to be able to quickly revert in case something goes wrong.