# Can I rename a partition of my external hard drive without damaging the files on the other partition? If so, how?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (it's a dual boot to windows 10 if that matters)
I could also do the renaming process on my mac. Also note that Ubuntu is on my computer hard drive, not the external.

I have an external hard drive with two partitions. One of them contains a large amount of important data (it would be difficult for me find a place to save this data while I do the partition). The other is empty.

I need to rename one of them (it can be the empty one) because they both have spaces in the name and this is interfering with some software and scripts I need to use.

Essentially, I want to know if it possible to rename the partition safely without backing up my files and, if so, how?

Comment: Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, renaming a partition, even if not empty, should not effect the data on it. Just be careful to rename, not repartition or reformat.

Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/276928/924681) for how to rename from either a GUI or terminal

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to re-label a partition. To cure your problem, remove the spaces in the label name, and replace them with "_" (underscores). ie: New_Label

**Note**: Keep in mind that changing labels may cause problems in scripts, mount points, /etc/fstab, or commands that require path names.

**Note**: File/disk backups are always a good idea.

In the `terminal`...

`sudo tune2fs -L new_label /dev/sdaX` # change the sdaX to the proper partition number

In `gparted`...

right-click on a partition and choose "Label File System"

In `Disks`...

from a pull-down menu and choose "Edit Filesystem Label"