# How would you combine a 1TB nvme with a 1TB HDD?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

My computed had a small 120GB sata SSD and a 1TB HDD, I used to use a partition of the SSD for the `/` mountpoint, and the HDD cached with bcache by another partition of the SSD for `/home`

Now I have a 1TB nvme SSD as well, but I'm wondering how to integrate it with the HDD already to keep the extra storage, but using 2 drives for the `/home` (with some folders going to the HDD like downloads and videos) and some files going to the nvme (like big workfiles or installations with data at `/home`) is quickly becoming annoying.

How would you combine the two drives into a single volume, without losing much of the performance of the nvme or much of the 2TB total space?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have some of your `/home` directory on the SSD with a few sub-directories on another device, you can do this by partitioning the HDD and mounting those partitions as directories in `/home`.

For example:

- you would like to have `~/Downloads` and `~/Videos` on the HDD
- you expect `~/Downloads` will never exceed 100GB
- you want `~/Videos` to use as much space as possible

To do this:

1. Create two partitions on the HDD using fdisk or Disks.
   *For the sake of this example, we'll call them* `/dev/sda1` *for the downloads, which is 100GB in size, and* `/dev/sda2` *for videos, which is 900GB in size.*
2. Format the partitions:

   ```
   sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda1
   sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda2
   ```
3. Mount the partitions to the appropriate locations:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/metichi/Downloads
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /home/metichi/Videos
   ```
4. Ensure you have proper permissions on the new locations:

   ```
   sudo chown -R metichi:metichi ~/Downloads
   sudo chown -R metichi:metichi ~/Videos
   ```

So long as everything is good, you can update the `/etc/fstab` file to auto-mount these locations at boot time:

1. Make a backup of `fstab`:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orig
   ```
2. Edit the `/etc/fstab` file as `sudo` with your preferred text editor. Add these lines:

   ```
   /dev/sda1    /home/metichi/Downloads    ext4    defaults    0    0
   /dev/sda2    /home/metichi/Videos       ext4    defaults    0    0
   ```
3. Reboot your system and make sure it all works

Be sure to replace `metichi` in the examples above with your actual username.

> **Notes:** Make sure your existing `~/Downloads` and `~/Videos` directories are empty when you are doing this, or you may lose access to the files already there.

Comment: Suggest using UUID or Label in fstab entry. If I plug in a flash drive or external SSD, my drives often change order. Then you will not be mounting correct partition(s). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab I do like to label all my partitions. I use gparted, disks or command line to set labels. https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions

Comment: That’s a very good point 