# Not able to use a partitions in Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I am not able to copy or extract files to, and even create new folder in the a partition that I have.I am able to copy files to and do other things in the other two partitions but not in the third one. What to do? I have attached some screenshots for reference. Pl. help ASAP.
Thanks in advance :)

[image: Not able to extract files]

[image: Not able to move files to that partition]

[image: Not able to create new folder]

Comment: The UUID makes me think there is a Linux file system in your partition(s). Then you can create a directory at the top level of the partition using elevated permissions `sudo mkdir /path-to-mountpoint/dirname` and then change ownership and/or permissions of that directory to make it easily available. This means that the user(s) should no longer need elevated permissions.

Comment: @sudodus One can leave the automatic mountpoint, and change its permissions. These are remembered the next time the drive is plugged in.

Comment: @vanadium, Will it be remembered also in other computers? In other words, is it portable?

Comment: Yes, the permission change remains - it is the permissions of the root folder you change, and these are being applied to the automatically created mount point when you plug in the drive or mount the partition through the file manager.

Comment: Sometimes, you may need to turn off fast startup in Windows to be able to access other NTFS partitions (not just the C drive)

Answer (score 2):

You are working with Linux. Linux handles security through file ownerships and permissions. For file systems that support linux permissions, the permissions of the root folder are in effect. By default, owner is the administrator: `root`, and currently on Ubuntu, the permissions by default are +rwx for user, +rwx for group and +rx for others.

If you want to use the drive fully for your current user, then change the permissions of the mount point:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/aaditya/15e16d9b-fbe1-4d51-ade6-2d7b4e2F9a86
```

You see that I retrieved the information on where this drive is mounted from your screenshot.

*Some advice not directly connected to the specific question* (with thanks to a comment of Oldfred)

- It is advisable to [label the drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions), so it is automounted with an easily recognizable name.
- If this is an internal drive that you use frequently, you better create a mount point and have it automatically mounted during startup by including it in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: If an internal partition, better to create mount point & permanently mount with fstab. If an external drive or a partition you only occasionally mount better to give it a useful unique label, so it auto mounts by label, rather than UUID. https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions

Comment: @oldfred obviously very good advise which I added to the question

Comment: chown: cannot access '/media/aaditya/15e16d9b-fbe1-4d51-ade6-2d7b4e2F9a86': No such file or directory   - It shows this

Comment: Check the precise name as displayed of your screenshot. I just copied it using OCR from your screenshot, so there may be a wrong letter or number. Better yet, type `sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/aaditya/15e` then hit Tab so the shell will autocomplete this folder name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed after I created a home partition out of that free space partition. Now I am able to manipulate and create files in that partition. Thanks for ur reply and comments. The link which I got help from -

https://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/