# I have 2 drives on Ubuntu. Can I use them together simultaneously?

Tags: partitioning

I do apologize. I am new to this IT customization.

```
 sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  19.5G  0 part /media/
├─sda2   8:2    0  13.7G  0 part /media/
├─sda3   8:3    0   4.1G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   428G  0 part /media/
└─sda5   8:5    0   500M  0 part /media/
sdb      8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0 118.9G  0 part /
```

Results of `cat /etc/fstab` :

```
ubuntufun@shisui:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=9A47-5A41                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=b41f7887-d80b-4afc-be14-d1955a56b44a /              ext4    defaults,discard 0 1
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

I setup Ubuntu on my desktop which contains 2 drives in it. I do believe I partitioned them (accordingly with sdb2 120GB SSD having the home folder, sda4 with 428GB currently free) when I installed Ubuntu and totally removed Windows. My intention was to use the SSD for running programs at a lightning pace and the slower hard drive with more space would contain folders that would be ideal for storing certain files/folders.

Now that the SSD is full to capacity, I cannot copy and paste from the SSD to the other drive (I am still new to Linux and have been slowly learning about its setup). I can see lib files, however neither copy and paste or creating a new folder options are not  available on the larger drive.

Comment: You are unable to use the `mv` command to move files from the SSD to the HDD? What specific error(s) are you receiving? 

Comment: It is not possible that all these partitions, sda1, sda2 etc are all mounted on the same directory /media.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/fstab`. Also, a more normal setup would be to have your / be on the SSD, and /home on the HDD.

Comment: I could not attain sudo permissions (common problem with Ubuntu as I found out) I just cracked that now after many attempts, I found this to work

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You have to be administrator, i.e., have `sudo` permissions, in order to manage storage media. Drive management and ownership requires some reading up. This cannot be covered in an answer here. so what follows are just some leads to get you started.

On Ubuntu, partitions are not automatically mounted after startup, unless they specifically have been configured to do so. On a default install, only the partition containing the system, i.e., the root partition, is mounted. It is mounted on the directory '/', the upper topmost folder in a linux system.

On Ubuntu, other partitions can be mounted before use by clicking the icon representing the partition in the left pane of the file manager Files. These partitions are then mounted by the system under a folder `/media/<userlogin>/<label>`.

It can be desired to also have data partition automatically mounted during startup. Power users can [edit the system configuration file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting) `/etc/fstab`  directly, but you can also use the utility "Disks" to configure a partition to automatically mount. In that tool, select the partition in the map, then click the cog wheel and select "Edit mount options". You must specify a mount point, i.e., a folder in which the entire partition will appear after mounting.

Next to the aspect of connecting a partition to your file system (mounting), there is also the issue of ownerships and permissions. By default, a user can only read and write in folders under his home folder (typical `/home/<login-name>`). Before users can write anywhere else, either they must be made owner of the folder, or they must belong to a group that has write permissions for the folder. Alternatively, the permissions for others  must be fully opened, but that is not safe practice.

A 120 SSD is plenty, both for the operating system and for storing user data that you use daily. In your case, I would work mostly from the SSD, and use the HD for storing archive data or large files like pictures and music. An elaborate scenario of a user arranging data in different partitions, and using links to make them accessible directly in the home folder is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk).

Comment: Some more info on data partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk  For partitions only occasionally used I like to label them, so mount is via label not some UUID which I do not know for sure what it is. you can use gparted or Disks to add labels. To see labels: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,UUID,mountpoint`  More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use ***/dev/sda*** as a 'data partition', as windows users usually put it.

It's quite straightforward to achieve. The way you think about it, however, has to change a little.

It's like you have a bunch of *bags*, and want to put stuff in them. The linux way is first to sew the *bags* up to your *jacket*, as if they're **genuine *pockets***.

So here we are talking about ***mounting partitions to where you store stuff*** which most often refer to **'/home/...'**, or *dirs* in your *HOME*. To complete the anology, **'/home/...'** denotes the sewn *pockets*, while **'/'** denotes your whole *jacket*, or the *ROOT PARTITION* (which in your case is ***/dev/sdb2***).

For example, you can mount ***/dev/sda4*** to **/home/data** as one *pocket*, and mount ***/dev/sda{1,2,3}*** to **/home/{video,music,doc}** as others.

Now the task is how you mount spare partitions to ***/home/...***. To achieve this, you need to:

1. Mount ***/dev/sda{4,1,2,3}*** to somewhere like ***/media/sda{4,1,2,3}***, repectively.
2. Move current data in **/home/...** to ***/media/sda{4,1,2,3}***, respectively.
3. Write all the *mount assignments* to **/etc/fstab**, one line for each partition, similiar to the original lines. (You need to learn how mount works, including its command syntax.)

**But before you begin, it's most important to think over and understand what you are about to do.**