# How to change volume/mount name of freshly mounted storage drives?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu desktop for a Plex server I am building, and I had to manually format/partition the two 4TB HDD's I installed. After using the command `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc` (and the same for the other drive name), it mounted both volumes and they show up in the navigation/status bar. I took ownership of them and I can create directories and such as planned.

The only problem is that navigating to them via the CLI is insane because the default name is like (for example) `69b547f6-78e5-4f16-b217-a82a8e106ad2`

How can I change this volume name (mount point?) to something simpler for easier navigation?

Comment: Why not give them specific mount points that you like, eg. my own systems are mounted via my editing *file-system table* (`/etc/fstab`) so they'll mount automatically exactly where I want them (*some even mount in more than a single location with different permissions too*).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab   *You didn't provide release details thus we can only be generic*

Comment: While mounting with fstab is best, I also have some partitions I only mount occasionally. So I label all partitions. Then they mount by the label I have given them. You can see labels: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid` I typically set label when creating partition with gparrted. I have used Disks or command line also. https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions

Comment: If you used `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc` then you wrote the filesystem straight to the device without making a partition first. Having done that I am not sure if you will be able to add a label as suggested by @oldfred

Comment: Missied that drive was formatted, not a partition. Drive should be gpt partitioned first. Without partitions many tools will have issues as they expect to see partitions.