# saving ubuntu settings to load into a new machine

Tags: 12.04, settings, transfer

I will soon be receiving a new machine (yes, I need the improved performance!) how can I transfer over all of my current Ubuntu settings and files to the new machine.

This is very important because I have many packages installed from `apt-get`, python packages, emacs packages and so forth. I really want to avoid installing all of the same packages over again. I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

1. What is the best solution in transferring my current ubuntu settings and files to a new machine?

Let me know if you need more information. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible Duplication: [How do I move (copy) my entire Ubuntu system to a different hard disk?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151127/how-do-i-move-copy-my-entire-ubuntu-system-to-a-different-hard-disk)

Answer (score 0):

To move your settings between Ubuntu machines, simply copy your home (~) folder to the other computer. It contains all your personal settings. To see hidden folders, type Ctrl+H. You may want to remove some of these folders after copying, as most of the settings in your home folder are actually stored by apps, not the system.