# How to backup my system so that I can create an exact replica on another computer

Tags: 12.10, hard-drive, backup, restore

I have a ubuntu 12 LTS and windows dual boot machine. My hard drive is going to fail soon and my machine has also become quite old now. I am buying a new computer soon. How can I restore my ubuntu copy on that machine?

I push all my code repos to the server, so I wont lose anything critical. But I would like not to have to make all the customization bash, webstorm settings, lxde bar, chrome etc. again.

Comment: Duplicate:http://askubuntu.com/questions/151127/how-do-i-move-copy-my-entire-ubuntu-system-to-a-different-hard-disk

Comment: Is there now new options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use RemasterSys to do this. It is currently out of development, but is still installable.

```
wget -qO - http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu [code] main
```

Insert either quantal or precise where [code] is. Newer code names DO NOT WORK!
After it is install, you should click Backup.