# Install Ubuntu to USB Flash Drives Automatically

Tags: usb-installation

I need to create many USB flash drives that run Ubuntu. These flash drives should:

1. contain **custom pre-installed software**
2. be persistent: even after restart, programs and **new files should be preserved**

How can I **automate** this process to avoid manual steps (except for plugging in the drives)?

Comment: Your link doesn't work...

Comment: @Graham Thanks for pointing this out! I edited the question to provide a cached link.

Comment: Your requirement for persistence seems to argue against using a Live image. Those are merely snapshots intended for trials and hardware testing. Their persistence, when enabled, is still limited.

Comment: @user535733 My thoughts exactly. This is just the only approach I found so far that I may be able to automate/script. If there is a better (automated) way, I am all for it.

Comment: Use `dd` to copy the complete system, and then [change the new system's partition UUID](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109938/change-hdds-uuid) so it no longer matches the original, then edit /etc/fstab to match the new UUID. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @user535733 Sounds promising! It would be awesome if you could provide a complete answer (or resource) that explains (1) how to create/obtain the original Ubuntu system (ideally automatically, if necessary manually) and (2) which exact commands to use to copy this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the advice by @user535733, I ended up doing the following:

## 1. Install Ubuntu/Lubuntu on a flash drive

These instructions loosely follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/983692/774965).

(Preparation)

- Create a live USB or DVD.
- Turn off and unplug the computer.
- Unplug all hard drives from your computer.
- Plug the computer back in.
- Disable secure boot and fast boot in UEFI settings (the exact steps for this
  are vendor-specific)

(Run Installer)

- Insert the Live USB or Live DVD.
- Start the computer, the USB/DVD should boot.
- Select Install Ubuntu.
- Insert a new target drive to install Ubuntu.
- Follow the instructions.
- Do not install "third-party software", as it may not work on other machines.
- At "Installation type" select "Something else".
- Select "Continue".
- Select target drive (in my case /dev/sdb)
- Select "New Partition Table" and "Continue".

(EFI partition)

- Click "Free space" and "+".
- "Size": 100 MB
- Select "Primary"
- "Location": "Beginning of this space"
- "Use as": "EFI System Partition"
- Select "OK"

(/ partition)

- Click "free space" and then "+".
- "Size": 7800 MB (or something else)
- Select "Primary"
- "Location": "Beginning of this space"
- "Use as": "Ext4"
- Mount point: "/"
- Select "OK"

(Important)

- Ensure "Device for boot loader installation" points to the root of the flash drive (/dev/sdb in my case).
- Click "Install Now" and "Continue".
- Follow the instructions.
- Wait until install is complete.

(Wrap up)

- Turn off computer and plug in the HDD.

## 2. Save the resulting flash drive

Next, save the resulting image to your machine. I wrote a script that handles
this step.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Saves flash drive partitions to disk
#
# Example Usage:
# ./copy.sh /dev/sde ./images

# enable bash strict mode
# http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

##########
# INPUTS #
##########

# Checking inputs
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "USAGE: ./copy.sh DEVICE OUTPUTDIR"
  echo "Available devices:"
  sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID,MODEL
  exit
fi

# parse inputs
DEVICE=$1
OUTPUTDIR=$2
EFIFILE=$OUTPUTDIR/ubuntu-efi.img
ROOTFILE=$OUTPUTDIR/ubuntu-root.img
PARTITIONFILE=$OUTPUTDIR/partitions.txt

# Display helpful information
echo "Saving device $DEVICE to $OUTPUTDIR:"
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID,MODEL $DEVICE

# Confirm
read -r -p "Continue? [y/N] " response
if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
    echo "Start copying (this could take a long time)..."
else
    echo "Aborting" >&2
    exit
fi

mkdir -p "$OUTPUTDIR"

########
# SAVE #
########

# record sizes
sudo fdisk -l | grep ${DEVICE} | sed "s#${DEVICE}#/dev/sdX#g" > $PARTITIONFILE

# dd: copy and convert
# if: source disk
# bs: sector size value from fdisk output
# count: last "end" sector from fdisk output incremented by one
# conv=sync,noerror: sync I/O and don't stop in case of errors on the source disk
sudo dd if=${DEVICE}1 conv=sync,noerror of=$EFIFILE
sudo dd if=${DEVICE}2 conv=sync,noerror of=$ROOTFILE
```

## 3. Install to New Drive

Finally, install the saved image to new flash drives. Again, I wrote a script
that handles this step.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Installs Ubuntu/Lubuntu to flash drive
#
# Example Usage:
# ./copy.sh /dev/sde ./images

###########
# HELPERS #
###########

# enable bash strict mode
# http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

# directory containing this script
BASEDIR="$( dirname "$0")"

# run commands at the end of the script (even on errors)
EXIT=""
function addExit {
    # call the argument before ending the script
    EXIT="$@ ; $EXIT"
    trap "echo 'Final tasks before exit...' ; $EXIT" EXIT HUP TERM INT QUIT
}

##########
# INPUTS #
##########

# Checking inputs
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "USAGE: ./copy.sh DEVICE SOURCEDIR"
  echo "Available devices:"
  sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID,MODEL
  exit
fi

# parse inputs
DEVICE="$1"
SOURCEDIR="$2"
MNT=/mnt

# Display helpful information
echo "Installing to device $DEVICE:"
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,UUID,MODEL $DEVICE

# Confirm
read -r -p "Continue? [y/N] " response
if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
    echo "Preparing partitions..."
else
    echo "Aborting" >&2
    exit
fi

# record sizes
PARTITIONFILE="$SOURCEDIR/partitions.txt"
EFISTART=$( cat "$PARTITIONFILE" | grep /dev/sdX1 | awk -F" "  '{ print $2 }')
EFIEND=$(   cat "$PARTITIONFILE" | grep /dev/sdX1 | awk -F" "  '{ print $3 }')
ROOTSTART=$(cat "$PARTITIONFILE" | grep /dev/sdX2 | awk -F" "  '{ print $2 }')
ROOTEND=$(  cat "$PARTITIONFILE" | grep /dev/sdX2 | awk -F" "  '{ print $3 }')

#######################
# COPY TO FLASH DRIVE #
#######################

# umount all paritions of this device
echo "Unmounting all partitions of $DEVICE..."
sudo umount $DEVICE?* || true

# create partition table
sudo wipefs --all $DEVICE
sudo parted $DEVICE mklabel gpt

# efi partition
sudo parted $DEVICE mkpart primary fat32 ${EFISTART}s ${EFIEND}s
sudo parted $DEVICE set 1 boot on
sudo parted $DEVICE set 1 esp on

echo "Start copying efi..."
EFIFILE="$SOURCEDIR/ubuntu-efi.img"
sudo dd if="$EFIFILE" of=${DEVICE}1

# root partition
sudo parted $DEVICE mkpart primary ext4 ${ROOTSTART}s ${ROOTEND}s
# sudo parted $DEVICE name 2 UbuntuUSB

echo "Start copying root (this could take a long time)..."
ROOTFILE="$SOURCEDIR/ubuntu-root.img"
sudo dd if="$ROOTFILE" of=${DEVICE}2

##################
# PREPARE CHROOT #
##################
# prepare running command in root directory of new installation

sudo mount ${DEVICE}2 $MNT
addExit "sudo umount $MNT"

sudo mount ${DEVICE}1 $MNT/boot/efi
addExit "sudo umount $MNT/boot/efi"

for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys; do
    sudo mount -B $i ${MNT}$i
    addExit "sudo umount ${MNT}$i"
done
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf $MNT/etc/
modprobe efivars

########
# GRUB #
########

# update grub
sudo chroot $MNT grub-install -d /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi/ --removable ${DEVICE}

#############
# CUSTOMIZE #
#############

# prepare scripts
sudo cp -r "${BASEDIR}/customize" "$MNT/opt/customize"

# install software
sudo chroot $MNT "/opt/customize/software.sh"
```

This script also installs additional custom software, using the following script
in `./customize/software.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# enable bash strict mode
# http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

###########
# PREPARE #
###########

# avoid locale issues and in order to import GPG keys
export HOME=/root
export LC_ALL=C

#######
# APT #
#######

apt-get update -y
apt-get clean
apt-get -y autoremove --purge

####################
# INSTALL SOFTWARE #
####################

# -y: auto-confirm
# -qq: quiet installation
apt-get install -y -qq \
    htop \
    gparted \
    build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a script doing all the necessary steps and execute it after installation.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

apt update
apt install -y \
    vlc \
    curl \
    git \
    filezilla \
    ... others to be installed

apt purge -y \
    thunderbird \
    ... others to be uninstalled

gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash false

apt upgrade -y
apt autoremove -y
```

You can even put the script somewhere online and run it via

```
wget -qO- https://example.com/script.sh | sudo bash
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This partially solves my problem, but still leaves me with (1) manually installing Ubuntu, (2) manually running the installed Ubuntu, and (3) manually triggering the script. Is there any way to automate those steps too?