# How can I run Disk Utility in terminal via a comand line?

Tags: command-line, disk-utility

First of all, I must say that I have successfully used Disk Utility in the past and thus I could rename my partitions.

But yesterday, I saw that my partitions are not mounted, so I used Storage Device Manager to make them to automatically mount at start up. That was a success also but I saw that the partitions are labelled as sda1 and sda7 not as they were initially. So I wonted to open again Disk Utility to rename them.

The problem is that, no matter how many times I try to open the application it just does't start at all! I don't know why it is doing this, as I have already told, I could use it in the past very well. I don't know if this "lack of reaction" of the application is the result of the actions I described before, or it is something else.

But I'm thinking of trying to start Disk Utility in terminal. Maybe I'll force it to run and solve the labelling problem. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Did you change your partitions, drive attachments to SATA, or USB ports, or did you make different setting in the BIOS before you device numbers had changed?

Comment: Hello! Sory to reply so late. No, I did not changed anything, especialy not in BIOS. At that time - when I have asked this question Ank Ubuntu - I was using an old HP desktop with a very weird BIOS. Apparently, the owner of the PC (it was not my PC) created a password for BIOS which he then forgotten, so I wasn't able to make any change in BIOS not even accidentally, because the "Exit and save" command wasn't working.

Comment: In case you still have this machine: you may be able to reset the BIOS password with a jumper on the Motherboard. Check with the manual.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Yes, I still have that machine, my mother uses it. No, I'm afraid I'm not very good in doing that jumper thing although I do have some idea. But when is about BIOS I can't risk to be shallow. What manual you are talking about? Do you know where I can find it? Thanks!

Comment: The computer may (or may not) have been sold with a manual for its motherboard. In the likely case you dont have access to it anymore you may find it online from HP. If that fails too - well, then you can try to open the computer, remove all the dust (which should be done anyway), and see if something conclusive is printed on the motherboard (CLR, CLEAR, CLR CMOS or similar). Some very old BIOSes also reset to default values when removing the backup battery for an hour or so. See also http://security.stackexchange.com/q/19665

Comment: This is another major problem with ubuntu that still isn't solved. There is no easy way to launch disk utilities as root so you can actually mount disks... windows has had right click icon and run as administrator for over 10 years.

Answer (score 49):

The application behind *"Disk Uitility"* changed in newer release versions. Hence the terminal command to call them is as follows:

#### For >= 12.10

```
gnome-disks
```

#### For earlier versions including 12.04:

```
palimpsest
```

Renaming partitions can also be done with a command line tool (no need to install and run gparted):

- [How to rename partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions)

Please note that the device and partition names `/sda`, resp. `/sda1 ... /sdaX` and `/sdb /sdc ..` do not depend on the disk label but are internal device numbers, depending on partition layout, SATA-port attachment, BIOS. To avoid confusion we have a unique UUID for each drive to mount it appropriately. This can be replaced by a label if needed.

- [Constant UUID on USB install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49290/constant-uuid-on-usb-install)

Comment: palimpsest? Good name.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative from the disk utility you can use Gparted. It is the best tool partitioning and managing of them.

to install gparted in your PC type as

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo fdisk -l` to list all drives in Ubuntu 21.10; it's like running `diskutil list` in macOS.