# Link to Windows desktop gets broken

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, mount, symbolic-link

I mount C:/, and I create a link from my Ubuntu desktop to Windows desktop. However, when I restart the computer, mount C again, and double click on the link, I get the error message `This link cannot be used because its target “/media/me/209A9ACE9A9AA038/Users/me/Desktop” doesn't exist.`

So I guess the `209A9ACE9A9AA038` part is some kind of hash that changes every time I mount C. So how can I make a link that will work persistently?

P.S. : I don't need auto-mount, but I want a link that will work whenever I mount the drive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A link to a (folder on) a partition only works if the partition is mounted, *or* the "link" is actually running a script, mounting the partition *and* opening the folder.

Comment: @JacobVlijm the latter sounds good. Any suggestions on how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

In case we need a partition to always mount at the same place, and to be reliably present it is recommended to auto-mount these partitions at boot or login.

This can be done by an entry to your `/etc/fstab` file for mounting at system boot, or by using `udisks` if mounting should only happen on user login.

See below questions on how to do that:

- For mounting at boot: [How to automount NTFS partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46588/how-to-automount-ntfs-partitions)
- For mounting at login: [Automatically mount NTFS drive when I login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83461/automatically-mount-ntfs-drive-when-i-login)

To better understand file systems and what mount options there are 2 other recommended place for further reading:

- [Ubuntu Community Wiki: Mount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount)
- [How to efficiently partition a single Windows-Ubuntu dual boot disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581902/how-to-efficiently-partition-a-single-windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-disk)

Please note that Windows partitions **must not be hibernated** for mounting on Ubuntu.

To avoid issues with a changing UUID we can also mount by a disk LABEL:

- [Constant UUID on USB install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49290/constant-uuid-on-usb-install/49296#49296)